# How to read relevant information from maven dependency tree using regex in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, maven

I am writing a script using Perl that should be able to generate list of dependent projects of given project.

**dependency-tree Perl script**

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
#Read dependency-tree file and split the dependencies
sub readDependencyTreeFile(){
  my ($dependencyTreeFile) = @_;
    open my $fh, '<', $dependencyTreeFile or die "error opening $dependencyTreeFile: $!";
    my $content = do { local $/; <$fh> };


    $content= ~/^com.myProject.sample:(.*?):jar:$/; 
    return $content;


}
my $dependencyTreeFile = "./dependency-tree.txt";
my $content = readDependencyTreeFile($dependencyTreeFile);
print $content;
```

**Dependency-tree.txt**

```
INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building myProject_10.5 10.5-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ myProject_10.5 ---
[INFO] com.myProject.sample:myProject_10.5:jar:10.5-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- com.myProject.sample:common_0.1:jar:0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.594 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-06-13T13:21:29+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 18M/309M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Expected Output**

```
myProject_10.5
common_0.1
```

But in my case regex is not worked as expected.Please let me know where it went  wrong.`$content= ~/^com.myProject.sample:(.*?):jar:$/;` this should filter `maven dependency tree` string into above out put.

Comment: You need to filter out the `[INFO] `. Get rid of the `^` and `$` anchors for a start.

Comment: You can give a configuration option to maven-depenedency-plugin like `-DoutputFile=result.txt` which contains everything as text...The question is why do you need that? Reporting ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of slurping the whole file in `$content`, you can process each line in the file, and use the following regexp with each line: `/^\[INFO\]\s.*?com\.myProject\.sample:([^:]+)/` to capture the dependency you need, and concatenate the matches as you find them.

Your sub would be something like:

```
sub readDependencyTreeFile(){
    my ($dependencyTreeFile) = @_;
    open my $fh, '<', $dependencyTreeFile or die "error opening $dependencyTreeFile: $!";
    my $content;
    while (my $line = <$fh>) {
        if ($line =~ /^\[INFO\]\s.*?com\.myProject\.sample:([^:]+)/) {
            $content .= $1 . "\n";
        }
    }
    return $content;
}
```

This assumes that there is only one "dependency" written on any given line, and that the lines having such information have the format you mentioned in your sample data, i.e.:

- they start with "[INFO]"
- there is a blank after that
- possibly after something the string "com.myProject.sample:" is found
- and it captures any following characters that are not a ":" (at least one character is needed for matching, i.e.: it has to be non-empty)
- the rest of the line is ignored

You should also add a `use warnings;` after your `use strict;`.